# Multiple simultaneous requests to MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database, locking

I have a problem may be you can help me:

I have a multiple requests using ajax to my PHP function for example at 10-00.

My PHP file function:

```
public function calculate(){
  $result = DB::query('SELECT * FROM `results` WHERE `time` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL "25" SECOND) ORDER BY `gameid` DESC LIMIT 1');
  if (intval($result->num_rows) > 0) {
     return json_decode($result->fetch_object()->data);
  } else {

      /*RESULT CALCULATION CODE /*SELECT FROM `players`....*/

      $publish_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  $result = DB::prepare("INSERT INTO `results` (`data`, `time`) VALUES (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `data` = VALUES(data), `time` = VALUES(time)");    
  $result->bind_param("ss", json_encode($arr), $publish_date);
  $result->execute();       
  $result->close();

  DB::query('TRUNCATE TABLE `players`'); /*WE CLEAN TABLE HERE*/
      return $arr;
   }
}
```

So one of my client requests should calculate results and store it in the table `results` at first.

Other requests should get info from `results` table without new calculation.
How can I solve this problem (LOCK TABLE???)?
Thanks!

Comment: Try to INSERT, if INSERT fails (with unique key), then somebody beat us to it, so SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use "INSERT IGNORE" in the INSERT statement you've written. This means that if the same result is already available, it will not be inserted again. This may very occasionally lead to two scripts calculating the result almost simultaneously. However, I don't think this will be a real problem, as this will presumably be very rare, and the calculation itself probably won't take very long (will it?) anyway. Any MySQL queries used to perform the calculation will also be answered from the query cache.

Alternatively, you could keep a list of results that are already being calculated in  shared memory: (http://php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php) and reference this list whenever you are about to start calculating a new result. I personally think this would be much more work than just relying on "INSERT IGNORE", unless it is vital for your application that every result be calculated only once.